# How to style a nested functional component using styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a button with the following props - `variant`, `loading`, and `disabled`. Plus, I have a button group that accepts buttons as children and gaps them with 20px. Something like this:

[image: Button specification]

Technically speaking, I have two components here. A `<Button />` and a `<ButtonGroup />`. This would be achievable by writing:

```js
const Button = styled.button`
  // css implementation

  :disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
`;

const ButtonGroup = styled.button`
  // css implementation

  ${Button} + ${Button} {
    margin-inline-start: 20px;
    // PS - I'm aware I could use the `gap` property, but I'm not specifically talking about this example, but in general.
  }
`;

// Usage
<ButtonGroup>
  <Button ... />
  <Button ... />
</ButtonGroup>
```

The last thing and the main issue here is to implement the loading state of the button. Or in general, adding extra logic to the styled component. So the "best" way I know of is to create a new functional component and then wrap it inside another styled. Something like this:

```js
// Button.tsx
const StyledButton = styled.buton`...`;

const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <StyledButton className={props.className}>
      {props.loading && <LoadingSpinner />}
      {props.children}
    </StyledButton>
  );
}

export default styled(Button)``; // It's needed for for nested styling.

...

// ButtonGroup.tsx
const ButtonGroup = styled.button`
  // css implementation

  ${Button} + ${Button} {
    margin-inline-start: 20px;
    // PS - I'm aware I could use the `gap` property, but I'm not specifically talking about this example, but in general.
  }
`;
```

It will work, of course, but I'm not sure if it's the best way. Currently, as you can see, I did it by calling styled component -> function component -> styled component for the simplest component. I'm not sure how it will scale with my other components, especially naming these components.

So my question is, is there a better, cleaner, simpler way of doing this?

Comment: I don’t think so. This looks to be a very common approach to nested styling.

Comment: "Better" "Clean" "Simple" are opinions, in my opinion, your approach seems ok, don't see any scale issues.

Comment: @DennisVash Might be opinioned, yes, but my point was that creating three components just for a simple task feels too verbose. At first, I call my component `StyledButton`, and then I create a new component which is just `Button`, and lastly, I create a new component which is a basically styled button as well. It's hard to reason about naming these. Plus, it'll give you hard time when you want to find references in any IDE. If this is the de-facto way of doing things, then I guess styled-components is just not my cup-of-tea.

Comment: Not sure why you need 3 components, two are enough as you already pass className, maybe try adding codesandbox

Comment: @DennisVash because otherwise, I won't be able to nest style the button (see the comment I wrote in `ButtonGroup`. If this is still unclear, let me know and I'll open a codesandbox example

Comment: You only need in addition to export `StyledButton` so you will be able to target `Button` component, I still don't see a reason why you need export `styled(Button)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a reason for three components, a pattern that works for me is using dot notation:

```
const StyledButton = styled.button``;
const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <StyledButton className={props.className}>
      {props.loading && <LoadingSpinner />}
      {props.children}
    </StyledButton>
  );
};

Button.Styled = StyledButton;
export default Button;
```

In this way, you have a pattern where `Component.Styled` (if available) will always hold the runtime CSS-in-JS object which you can target.

Then in `ButtonGroup` implementation:

```
import { Button } from "@components";

// You can target the className
const ButtonGroup = styled.div`
  ${Button.Styled} { ... }
`;

// You can apply styles
styled(Button)

// You can use the component
<Button />

// Or extend style etc
<OtherButton as={Button.Styled} .../>
```