# How to extend component style in styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a basic ElipseDetail component that looks like the image below

[image]

```
<ElipseDetail text="1.07" />
```

When I am using the component everything works as expected.

But now I want to reuse the component in another place but add an extension to the Text component style

How can I achieve that with styled-components and reuse the component but change the Text which is a child?

```
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface Props {
  text: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}


export const Container = styled.div`
  padding: 4px 12px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #eaeef2;
  display: inline-block;
`;

export const Text = styled.p`
  font-size: 12.5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.63px;
  color: #687c97;
`;


export default function ElipseDetail({ text, children }: Props): ReactElement {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
      {children}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since  ElipseDetails is not a styled component, but calls to a styled one, you can do something like:

```js
function ElipseDetail({ text, children }: Props): ReactElement {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
      {children}
    </Container>
  );
}

ElipseDetail.Styled = Container;

export default ElipseDetail
```

And then, in a different component, you can change it like so:

```
const StyledElipseDetail = styled(ElipseDetail.Styled)`
  ${Text} {
    //
  }
`;

...

return <StyledElipseDetailed>...</StyledElipseDetail>
```

PS - I have taken this approach from an [older question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65760415/how-to-style-a-nested-functional-component-using-styled-components) which I found quite useful.

Comment: hi, Eliya it seems great, but where do I pass my props?

Comment: @Harel Props of what exactly?

Comment: ElipseDetail component has a text prop, When I creating StyledElipseDetailed it is the Wrapper and not the whole component

Comment: Oh, you mean `styled<Props>(ElipseDetail)`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a container and if `Text` is in that container then add different properties. `&` here means this class name  so it evaluates to `Text` so when text would be in `ElipseContainer` then it will behave in different way depending on your use case. Here if it's wrapped with `ElipseContainer`  then colour of `Text` is green and it's red otherwise.
Here is sandbox link :
[sandobx](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-styled-components-forked-x3tws?file=/src/index.tsx)

```
const ElipseContainer = styled.div``;

const Text = styled.p`
  color: red;

  ${ElipseContainer} & {
    color: green;
  }
`;

 const App =() =>   
      <ElipseContainer>
        <ElipseDetail text="word2" />
      </ElipseContainer>
```